When hosting a Blazor Server app in an App Service behind an Application Gateway - should I expect timeouts?
We have a Blazor server application which I have hosted by an App Service. It all runs as expected.
When we use an Azure Application Gateway in front of this service we see a 'reconnecting' message every 20 seconds. I understand that the default timeout for requests is 20 seconds.
My query is - is this just something we have to put up with? Should I just customise the reconnection handler to be less obtrusive to the end user or is there some deeper configuration that I am not aware of?

Hi @AndyP9, If your application is not connecting within 20 seconds while being accessed through the application gateway, you can increase the timeout of your backend (application) as shown here in application gateway.

Thanks for the response @VenkatV - we have tried that and it helps but of course you do eventually get that timeout. Websockets is supposed to be a persistent connection. I'm just trying to ascertain if this reconnection issue is the trade-off we just have to put up with when using Application Gateway.

Request timeout is mandatory option in application gateway waits to receive a response from the backend. To avoid the issue, you can change timeout seconds in backend settings.


When we use an Azure Application Gateway in front of this service we see a 'reconnecting' message every 20 seconds. I understand that the default timeout for requests is 20 seconds.

If the application runs successfully when accessed through the app service URL but you face an error when accessing it through the application gateway, it may be because the application takes longer to reconnect. The application gateway will wait until the request timeout period is reached, and then it will throw an error
To resolve the issue, you can increase the request timeout in the backend settings of the application gateway. This will help your application maintain the connection for a longer period of time.

When an application is configured in an application gateway, the application gateway enforces its own request timeout settings by default, regardless of any timeout settings configured at the application level.
I have created an application and configured it in an App Service with an Application Gateway.

Reference:  Getting gateway timeout in Azure application gateway  by  msrini-MSFT
